# What is limiting requests count? Why `Timeout while getting a connection from pool`?

Tags: c#, postgresql, nhibernate, npgsql

At high load conditions NHibernate sometimes throws an exception when BeginTransaction is called. The message contains `Timeout while getting a connection from pool` in the RequestConnector method of Npgsql.

In the pg_log: `could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

Postgres stats doesn't show any expensive queries.

The machine have enough free cpu and ram resources.

Versions: Postgres 9.4.0 64-bit, NHibernate 3.3.1.4000, Npgsql 2.2.3.

Postgres settings:

```
shared_buffers = 128MB
max_connections = 300
checkpoint_segments = 6
```

Connection string settings:

```
Pooling = true;
MINPOOLSIZE=20;
MAXPOOLSIZE=1000;
```

Postgres and the application are located on the same machine.

All NHibernate transactions and sessions are disposed with `using`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was caused by disk bottleneck. With SSD it works much better.

Answer (score 0):

One problem that I have seen in the past is the maximum number of sockets that can be opened at the same time and the linger time from the time that a socket is closed till it is freed.  Under huge volumes this has become problematic.  Here are a couple of links that discuss this problem [Link 1](http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-tcpip-max-limit.html) [Link 2](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html)

Comment: netstat shows that there are only 34 TIME_WAIT connections and all of them have random ports like 57nnn, not 5432.

Answer (score 0):

We have noticed similar problem, I found at Npgsql github, that they have changed DNS resolving from sync to async in version 2.1 and it leads to this error. 
Till today (ver. 2.2.4.3) it is not fixed.

Here is a fix (revert): 
[Npgsql fork - commit](https://github.com/miloszes/npgsql/commit/308c79e0c8ae11562320ca7f6cf8aea0b289a0cb)